# How can I get ajax to read data from multiple HTML class elements

Tags: html, ajax

What I am trying to do is record the record number of a scholarship that is dynamically created on a page and post that result to the server without refreshing the page. It works now, but the problem is that it reads the ID and always returns ONLY the first item # in the list.

The code of the modal that lists each scholarship is the following:

```
 <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
 <button type="button" onclick="saveData()" value="<? echo $row['id'];  ?>" 
id="savedata" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" class="saveData" data- 
toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<? echo $row['id']; ?>">More Information. 
</button>
```

I have not included all the information for the modal but I am fairly sure that the issue is in the button part of the code.

The ajax part of the code that gets run when the button is clicked is:

```
<script>
function saveData(){

  var name=$('#savedata').val();



$.ajax({
   type:"post",
   url:"includes/post_scholarship_count.php",
   data:'name='+name,


});

}
</script>
```

The problem is when you click on any of the scholarships you get the first scholarship value even though I can see that the page has rendered out each scholarship with a unique value. My assumption is that because its an ID that its only going to take the first value. How can I get the variable in the ajax script to read from a HTML CLASS instead of the ID?

I have been trying to solve this for days so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pay attention at the answer I'm gonna post here in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a basic problem there and is the following. I assume you have lots of scholarships and thus lots of buttons. The ID html attribute is to name just a unique element in the page. As you see above you are referencing: #savedata, which will always reference just a single element.

So, my advice is the following and it includes a couple of items:

1. Use un-obstrusive javascript to handle your button events
2. Use HTML class attribute to reference the buttons instead of ID which is unique.

So let's explain it here

**Use un-obstrusive javascript and the class html attribute to attach events**

Instead of using the ID #saveData, just use the 'saveData' class attribute and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(evt){
    $('.saveData').on('click', function(e){
        var name = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"includes/post_scholarship_count.php",
            data:'name='+name,
        });
    });
});
```

This code will pick up all the buttons with a class `saveData` and attach them an event to process its click. And it will identify each button separatly. As an individual "click listener" is attached to each button, once you click a button it will know what to do.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer, it is clearly explained and works great. I had a feeling I had to use a class to do it but couldn't get that to work for me. Thanks so much for the great help.

Comment: You may vote the answer up and it'd help too. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to but I don't have enough point to do so. I did click that this was the answer, but the rules of this site are a bit constricted. IMOP

Answer (score 0):

You can reach elements by class in pure Javascript.

```
var name = document.getElementsByClassName("saveData");
```

But then you will get an array of elements! Perhaps you have to iterate through this array to get your values.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is an  approach using a generated table from php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container" id="exampleDiv">
    <?php
    $arrayName =array(
      array('Firstname' => 'Stan','Lastname' => 'Chacon', 'Middlename' => '', 'Nickname' => 'Zec' ),
      array('Firstname' => 'Annie','Lastname' => 'Smith', 'Middlename' => 'Derav', 'Nickname' => 'AnnieDSmith' ),
      array('Firstname' => 'Winnie','Lastname' => 'Pooh', 'Middlename' => '', 'Nickname' => 'WinnieTPooh' ),
    );
    //append an id to your table also a tbody
    $html="<table id='exampleTable' class='table table-striped' ><tr><th style='border: 2px solid grey;'>Firstname</th>
    <th style='border: 2px solid grey;'>Lastname</th>
    <th style='border: 2px solid grey;'>Middlename</th>
    <th style='border: 2px solid grey;'>Nickname</th>
    <th style='border: 2px solid grey;'>Action</th></tr><tbody>";

    foreach ($arrayName as $key => $value) {
      if (isset($value)) {
        $html.="<tr><td>{$value['Firstname']}</td><td>{$value['Lastname']}</td><td>{$value['Middlename']}</td><td>{$value['Nickname']}</td><td> <button type='button' name='buttonModal'>click me !</button></td></tr>";
      }
    }

    $html.="</tbody></table>";
    echo $html;

    ?>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
     <div class="modal-content">

       <!-- Modal Header -->
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       </div>

       <!-- Modal body -->
       <div class="modal-body">
       </div>

       <!-- Modal footer -->
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#exampleTable tbody tr td button").on('click',function(){
    var Firstname = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
    var Lastname = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(1)').text();
    var Middlename = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(2)').text();
    var Nickname = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(3)').text();

    if (Firstname != undefined && Lastname != undefined && Middlename != undefined && Nickname !=undefined) {
      $('.modal-body').empty();
      $("#myModal").modal();
      $('.modal-body').append('<p>Hello '+Firstname+' '+ Lastname+' looks like the Nickname '+Nickname+' is already in use!! Pls try to use another one</p>')
    }
    })

  </script>
</html>
```

Hope it helps !!